# Troubles getting CSS transition to work

Tags: css, opera, css-transitions

I'm trying to get my head wrapped around CSS3 transitions, and I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my understanding, or if the browsers aren't cooperating.

First of all, I thought Opera was supposed to have support for transitions, since version 10 or so, but neither `transition` nor `-o-transition` seems to do anything in 11.62. Or does Opera use a different syntax?

Anyway, I can make a background color fade in and out on hovering with most other browsers by writing

```
div {transition:background 2s;}
div:hover {background:lime}
```

OK so far, and I can also make it so that the background fades in, but not out, by writing

```
div:hover {transition:background 2s; background:lime}
```

and that the background fades out, but not in, like so:

```
div {transition:background 2s;}
div:hover {transition:background 0s; background:lime}
```

But I don't understand why that happens. According to the docs, a transition with a `0s` duration isn't supposed to have any effect, so why does the last one have a different result?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZTuM/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example it looks like it's behaving as I'd expect it.
The transitions run from one state to another.

I'll try an explain this as best I can.

On the last one you have a trasition of 2s on the `<div>` in its normal state and a a transition of 0s on the  `<div>` in it's hover state.

## So what is happening?

1. When you hover on the `<div>`, the state changes to `:hover` and so the transition for `div:hover` is run. You have a trasition of 0s so no animation is run.
2. When you remove the mouse from the `<div>` the state changes from `:hover` back to normal, and so the transition for `div` in its normal state is run. You have this at 2s.

Does this explain what is happening and how the transitions work?

Comment: Yes, I get it now. The div:hover in my first example is still, of course, the same div, so it also gets the transition value of the div, unless you override it. I hadn't got the CSS selectors straight. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you are looking for is the [`ease`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/timing-function#ease) timing function.

So your CSS rule should look something like this.

```
.class {
    transition: property(ies) duration timing-function;
}

.class:hover {
    property(ies): new value;
}
```

For Opera you have to define the exact property. In your case it wouldn't be the *background* property but the *background-color* property.

Comment: Double team answer: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/WZTuM/5/ here is an example of what @Octavian is talking about but with MUCH cleaned up CSS.

Comment: +1 for the remark about Opera. That works, thanks! However, DigitalBiscuits actually helped me solved my issue.

Comment: @rlemon Thanks. But in your jsFiddle, the three lines now all act the same. I was actually looking for the fade-in-but-not-out and fade-out-but-not-in effects the way I posted in my question.

Comment: That is not really true. Every line behaves as an autonomous object and transitions independently. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WZTuM/7/) is the same example just with a higher duration.